# Check table rows whether it is empty or not

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm working on dictionary database, I insert the query when the activity is first launch, it works smoothly, and at the next launch I want to prevent the insertion for the second time, I use this method to prevent insertion by checking whether the row is null or not, but it always rise a java null pointer exception in my logcat.

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    boolean empty = false;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + SQLiteHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null);

    if(cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getInt(0)== 0)
        {
            empty = false; //rows not null;
        }
        else
        {
            empty = true; // rows null;
        }
    }
    return empty;
}
```

this is my code for insertion in the main activity that will execute on every launch

```
if(datasource.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        try
        {
            datasource.opentowrite();
            datasource.Insert("aback", "tertegun");
            datasource.Insert("abacus", "dekak-dekak");
            datasource.Insert("abandon", "meninggalkan");
            datasource.Insert("abase", "menghinakan");
            datasource.Insert("abesement", "penghinaan");
            datasource.Insert("abash", "memberi malu");
            datasource.Insert("abate", "mengurangkan");
            datasource.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database faulty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database ready", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and this is the logcat

```
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dictionary/com.dictionary.Dictionary}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.dictionary.KamusDataSource.isEmpty(KamusDataSource.java:36)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.dictionary.Dictionary.onCreate(Dictionary.java:29)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-15 06:41:06.547: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  ... 11 more
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your database variable is **null** and that is reason of **NPE**. So you need to ensure that variable will be initialised if is null.

So here is method with condition how to achieve it:

```
public void methodName() {
    if (database == null) { // this will ensure that database will be initialised
       // if is null
       database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); // or similar method that
       // that returns new SQLiteDatabase instance
    }
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName", null);
    if (cursor != null) {
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry can you give an example of initialisation of database?

Comment: so did you create some dbhelper, right? so make something like database = dbhelper.getWriteableDatabase().

Comment: Yes I've did it in this class, I have two method, one for read and another to write

`public void opentowrite() throws SQLException
 {
  database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 }
 
 public void opentoread() throws SQLException
 {
  database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
 }`

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto ok so use it database = opentowrite(); but make sure  that dbhelper is initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    boolean empty = false;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + SQLiteHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null);


    if(cursor.getCount > 0)
    {
        empty = false; //rows not null;
    }
    else
    {
        empty = true; // rows null;
    }
}
return empty;
}
```

Comment: Is this line throws the exception:  if(datasource.isEmpty() == false)

Comment: So it look like datasource maybe null. Why don't you log datasource to see if it is null or not?